# Set margin for a preference screen

Tags: android

I have a preference screen in a Preference Fragment Compat that is one of four fragments hosted by the main activity and I switch between them by a bottom navigation view. The problem is that some of my preferences are under the bottom navigation view and unreachable! How can I add some bottom margins to the preference screen and solve the problem? This is my preference screen and I tried `android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"` but it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_marginBottom="57dp">

<!-- my preferences -->

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are adding your Fragment in a FrameLayout, you can simply add margins to the FrameLayout!

if not you should do like that -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"
            app:elevation="5dp"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I' adding them to a view pager. should I set margins for view pager?